# How to avoid creating all fields in child classes with inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

I have three entities and i have one parent class. Tarifa entity has "pvp" column, so I don't want it in "servicio" entity. The problem is that jpa force me to create column "pvp" in "servicio" table because i am using inheritance. Is there some way to avoid creating "pvp" column in "servicio" table?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tarifa")
@AttributeOverride(name = "nombre", column = @Column(name = "nombre", insertable = false, updatable = false))
public class Tarifa extends Concepto
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tarifa")
private List<Servicio> servicios = new ArrayList<Servicio>();
/*@Column(name="pvp")
private float pvp;*/
@Column(name="descuento")
private float descuento;
@Column(name="fecha_inicio")
private Date fechaInicio;
@Column(name="fecha_fin")
private Date fechaFin;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="producto")
public class Producto extends Concepto
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(name="descripcion")
private String descripcion;
@Column(name="stock")
private int stock;
@Column(name="coste")
private float coste;
/*@Column(name="pvp")
private float pvp;*/
@OneToMany(mappedBy="producto")
private List<DetalleFactura> detalleFactura = new ArrayList<DetalleFactura>();
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="servicio")
@AttributeOverride(name = "pvp", column = @Column(name = "pvp", insertable = false, updatable = false))
public class Servicio extends Concepto
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="id_tarifa")
private Tarifa tarifa;
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="id_animal")
private Animal animal;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="servicio", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private CitaServicio citaServicio;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="servicio")
private List<DetalleFactura> detalleFactura = new ArrayList<DetalleFactura>();
```

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Concepto
{
@Column(name="nombre")
private String nombre;

@Column(name="pvp")
private float pvp;
```

Comment: Just a OOP thought: "If `Servicio` has no `pvp`, then it's not a `Concepto`". Think about rearranging your class hierarchy. Think about `Concepto extends AbstractConcepto` where `AbstractConcepto` has no `pvp` and let `Servicio` extend from `AbstractConcepto` => http://cosketch.com/Saved/pcY4Z36P

Comment: Thanks, It worked!! But I have the same problem with "Tarifa" entity. I don't need "nombre" field so, how can I do it?